# How to accept 3 char values, convert them to int, add them and print out a particular message based on the total value?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that gets the user to enter 3 string characters only and will be unlocked if the modulus is zero after dividing by 5. I am trying to use ascii to convert the letters to int values and I am also trying to work out of how to combine the totals and check if the remainder is 0 and print out the desired message below.

I think I have my validation ok for a-zA-Z, but I know I am doing something wromg blending the convert to int values and printing out the password unlocked message into my code.

I am sure there is numerous errors , my apologies!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total=0;
        Scanner scnObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter 3 letters");
        String input1 = null;
        char[] arr=input1.toCharArray(); 
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            int ascii=(int)arr[i];
            if(ascii>=97&&ascii<=122)
            { // 
                total=total+ascii-96; 
            } 
            else if(ascii>=65&&ascii<=90)
            {
                total=total+ascii+36;  
            }

        }

        do {
            input1 = scnObj.next();

            if ((!Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{1}").matcher(input1).matches())) {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again.");
            }
        } while (!Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{1}").matcher(input1).matches());

        System.out.println("enter 2nd letter");
        String input2;
        do {
            input2 = scnObj.next();
            if ((!Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{1}").matcher(input2).matches())) {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again.");
            }
        } while (!Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{1}").matcher(input2).matches());

        System.out.println("Please enter the 3rd letter");
        String input3;
        do {
            input3 = scnObj.next();
            if ((!Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{1}").matcher(input3).matches())) {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again");
            }
        } while (!Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{1}").matcher(input3).matches());

        total= input1 += input2 += input3;
        if (total%5 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Password unlocked");
            else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect password");
            }   

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove your first part of code (the ASCII one)  you are not using it. In second part try this `total= ((int) input1.charAt(0)) + ((int) input1.charAt(0)) + ((int) input1.charAt(0));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the general idea right, but there are several things that are wrong and several things that can be done better.

1. `char[] arr=input1.toCharArray();`. This will always throw a `NullPointerException`, because at this point the `input1` string is still `null`.
2. The loop that adds things to the total should be executed after the string is read from the console.

Here's the updated code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter 3 letters");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]$");

        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();

            while (!pattern.matcher(input).matches()) {
                System.out.println("You must enter a letter");
                input = scanner.nextLine();
            }

            int letter = input.charAt(0);

            if (letter >= 97 && letter <= 122) {
                total += letter - 96;
            } else if (letter >= 65 && letter <= 90) {
                total += letter + 36;
            }
        }

        if (total % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Password unlocked");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect password");
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I've updated the code to ask the user to enter the letters one by one. You just need to move reading the input into the loop and update the regex.

Comment: Sorry @Tolik Pylypchuk I seem to be getting a loop error with your code. It keeps saying "You must enter 3 letters"

Comment: @Nexus_Valentine what letters are you entering?

Comment: Any letter from the alphabet is requested from the user 3 separate times uppercase or lowercase is accepted.

Comment: This implementation asks the user only once for the whole string. So try entering `aaa` and then enter. If you really need to ask the user for 1 letter 3 times, then I'll edit my answer.

Comment: My apologies I actually do need to specifically ask the user for 1 letter 3 times and gather the input etc. I'll give you the credit don't worry haha

Comment: @Nexus_Valentine I've updated my answer to ask the user to enter the letters one by one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204801/discussion-between-tolik-pylypchuk-and-nexus-valentine).

Answer (score 0):

Pass your regex pattern to the `Scanner.next()` method to accept only valid input. Run a loop to collect the 3 input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scnObj = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter 3 letters");
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String input;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter letter no " + (count + 1));
            input = scnObj.next("[a-zA-Z]");
            sum += input.charAt(0);
            count++;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            scnObj.next();
            System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again.");
        }
    } while (count < 3);

    if (sum % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Password unlocked");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect password");
    }

}
```

Comment: What error? I see the following output. `enter 3 letters
Enter letter no 1
1
Invalid entry, please try again.
Enter letter no 1
s
Enter letter no 2
d
Enter letter no 3
f
Incorrect password`